# How Android handles removed APIs

Tags: android, upgrade, android-6.0-marshmallow, deprecated

I am trying to understand how Android manages deprecated APIs. For example, a device running Android 5 has an app built with `targetSdk` 22 (i.e., Android 5.1). This app calls `android.provider.Browser.getAllBookmarks()`, which is deprecated since API 23. Then the device is upgraded to Android 6. All the concept of browser bookmarks was completely removed in Android 6, as far as I understand. So what will happen when the app is used? How does Android handle this situation?

Comment: just for clarification: when the device is upgraded, do you also imply updating the targetSdk?

Comment: No. I mean there is an app that nobody plans to upgrade - it will stay forever API 22. How will it behave after the upgrade? Will it crash? Will the provider return empty data set? Will it see the data it saw before the upgrade?

Comment: If it has been removed for some security reasons, android will respond with an empty state (null or empty data) that won't crash your app (this has been done before with the introduction of run-time permissions).

Answer (score 0):

This might help: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#fc

> Android applications are **generally forward-compatible** with new
>   versions of the Android platform.
>
> Because almost all changes to the framework API are additive, an
>   Android application developed using any given version of the API (as
>   specified by its API Level) is forward-compatible with later versions
>   of the Android platform and higher API levels. The application should
>   be able to run on all later versions of the Android platform, except
>   in isolated cases where the application uses a part of the API that is
>   later **removed for some reason**.